# How to add const qualifiers in template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to `const_value_type` be const even if `T` is a pointer, which is not possible with `std::add_const<>`
So I tried something like this:

```
template<typename value_type, bool is_pointer>
struct add_const_pointer{
    typedef const value_type type;
};

template<typename value_type>
struct add_const_pointer<value_type, true>{
    typedef const value_type *type;
};

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef add_const_pointer<std::remove_pointer<T>, std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type const_value_type; 
    // here I get compiler error: missing type specifier - int assumed.
}
```

but I get compiler error: missing type specifier - int assumed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`clang`](http://rextester.com/FUW65712) error message would help

```
typedef typename add_const_pointer<
//      ~~~~~~~~ Add typename
                  std::remove_pointer<T>, 
                  std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type 
                  const_value_type;
```

Comment: Thank you very much... now I am not sure why I have to add typename